# always getting 0 for rows affected by dbexecute

Tags: sql, r

I am trying to get the number of rows affected by an update query. I am using a pool connection to a SQL server database. The rows update fine, but I can't figure out how to get the number of rows affected which I want to display for the user. I have read the documentation of dbExecute and it says:

> dbExecute() always returns a scalar numeric that specifies the number
>   of rows affected by the statement. An error is raised when issuing a
>   statement over a closed or invalid connection, if the syntax of the
>   statement is invalid, or if the statement is not a non-NA string.

I thought maybe the pool was the issue, so I also tried it with a regular dbConnect, and still got 0 for res.

Can someone show how I can pull out and display to the user the number of rows affected?

```
    observeEvent(input$recupdate, {

    res <-
      #poolWithTransaction(con2, function(con2) {
        dbExecute(con2, paste(
          "UPDATE [Test_DB].[dbo].[mlt] SET testvar = 1 where idnum in ('",
          trim(paste(filteredData()$idnum, collapse="','")),"')", sep=""))  
      #})


    #print(res)    
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Rows affected:",
      res,
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL
    ))

  })
```

Comment: Dave916, I think this will be difficult to troubleshoot. I verified with a `pool` (using `odbc`) connection to a SQL Server instance, used `UPDATE ...`, and received a non-zero return value, so if you are using the same packages ... I don't know. You include some `shiny` here but it doesn't seem relevant to the question. Can you reproduce these results on the console without `shiny` involved?

Comment: (Side note: consider using `dbBind` or other methods for matching data. This case looks simple in that the `$idnum` is likely from a previous query, but especially when human interaction -- other than you --  is involved, you should get in the habit of being defensive against accidental or even malicious SQL injection. See https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/ and https://xkcd.com/327/.)